# Programmatically prefetching with Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I am navigating programmatically in Gatsby like so:

`navigate(nextRoute?.url || '/', { replace: true });`

The `nextRoute` is determined on mount. This works. However, I want this to function like the standard `Link` component, which uses preloading, as [described](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/):

> Preloading is used to prefetch page resources so that the resources are available by the time the user navigates to the page

I've seen [hacks](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/20568#discussioncomment-104944) around this, which don't seem to work for me, along with mysterious stirrings of so-called "[undocumented](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/8122#issuecomment-827193071)" functions. I've even tried the brutish solution of just highjacking the `Link` and [invoking it](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/8122#issuecomment-910507293) with fudged MouseEvents. All this seems a bit arcane to me, I just want to leverage the preloading API without having to rely on the `Link` component, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `<Link>` with the `to` prop equal to a variable in your component state that is changed when your component mounts (either through `setState` in `componentDidMount` or the hook equivalent).

Comment: I tried that, however I need to do it programatically as there are certain events that need to happen _before_ I navigate, such as a state update and a sound being played.